# asp:DataPager onclick event

Tags: asp.net, listview, onclick, datapager

I am working with the .Net List view along with a data pager to enable pagination for a list view.

I am able to set the pagination working perfectly for the list view but I wish to have a method being called when ever the user clicks on any of the page numbers in the data pager.

I want to perform some operation whenever the page number is called. I guess there is no onclick event, so is there any other way by which this is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set it as imagebutton or linkbutton.

I have piece of code.. you just need to implement it.

you can set link and click event.

```
foreach (DataPagerFieldItem dpfItem in dtpPaging.Controls)
            {
                foreach (Control cPagerControls in dpfItem.Controls)
                {
                    if (cPagerControls is ImageButton)
                    {
                        ImageButton imgNavigation = cPagerControls as ImageButton;
                        imgNavigation.PostBackUrl = CommonLogic.GetFormattedURL(strPageUrl);
                        imgNavigation.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imgNavigation_Click);

                    }
                    if (cPagerControls is LinkButton)
                    {
                        LinkButton lnkNumbers = cPagerControls as LinkButton;
                        lnkNumbers.PostBackUrl = CommonLogic.GetFormattedURL(strPageUrl);
                        lnkNumbers.Click += new EventHandler(lnkNumbers_Click);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bind a handler to the [`OnPagePropertiesChanging`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.pagepropertieschanging(v=vs.110).aspx) Event of the List View. A `PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs` object is passed to the handler as argument which contains `MaximumRows` and `StartRowIndex` properties. You can use these to calculate the current page number. It is very easy and requires no code-behind event binding as the solution proposed by sikender.